# Open a second file and quit the previously opened one without saving

Tags: buffers, hidden-buffers

If I do something like this:

```
vim
i
# Write some tmp text
# This tmp file served it's purpose, want to quit this one and open a new one
:e newfile
# E37: No write since last change (add ! to override)
```

To avoid that I end up doing this:

```
vim
i
# Write some tmp text
:q!
vim newfile
```

Am looking for a way to do it without the need to quit vim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to add the following line to your vimrc:

```
set hidden
```

From [`:h 'hidden'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27hidden%27):

```
'hidden' 'hid'      boolean (default off)
            global
            {not in Vi}
    When off a buffer is unloaded when it is abandoned.  When on a
    buffer becomes hidden when it is abandoned.
```

This option allows you to change of buffer even if the modifications were not saved.